# Adding parent key to this json output

Tags: json, node.js, restify

I am using restify module on node.js to build a REST API server.

I have this simple API using restify.

```
var api_get_sample = function (app, url_name) {
    function respond(req, res, next) {
        var door = req.query.door;
        var connection = custom_mysql.getMySQL_connection();
        var query_str =
                "SELECT XXX, YYY " +
                "FROM TABLE_X " +
                "WHERE door = ? "
            ;
        var query_var = [door];
        var query = connection.query(query_str, query_var, function (err, rows, fields) {
            //if (err) throw err;
            if (err) {                
                console.log(err);                
            }
            else {
                res.send(rows);
            }
        }); //var query = connection.query(query_str, function (err, rows, fields) {
        return next();
    }

    app.get(url_path, url_name);
};
```

It outputs a json which looks like this;

```
[{
    "ID": 1,
    "NAME": "James",

},
{
    "ID": 2,
    "NAME": "John",

}]
```

I would like to add a parent key to the json output such that it looks like this;

```
["Parent_key_added": {
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "NAME": "James",

    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "NAME": "John",

    }
}]
```

How do I manipulate the variable `rows` which is actually an array of RowDataPacket to add the key `Parent_key_added`?

Comment: var b = { parent_key: rows};

Comment: and your json is not valid, return  "[" and "]" to objects array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else {
            res.send({ parent_key: rows});
        }
```